# How to do multithreading in Entity Framework Core without violating SOLID principles?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, dbcontext

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API application, using Entity Framework Core 7 to connect to the database. I understand the concept of dependency injection and the fact that using `AddDbContext` I can inject specific DbContext to any object for the lifespan of the request.

And it works great **UNTIL** I want to do some database requests in parallel. Here is a sample class that is responsible of fetching data from database:

```
public class CarData : ICarData
{
    private readonly CarContext _car;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public CarData(CarContext car, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _car = car;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public bool CarExists(int carId)
    {
        return _car.Cars.Any(b => b.CarId == carId);
    }

    public async Task<CarDetailsOutput> GetCarDetails(int carId)
    {
        return (await GetCarsDetails(new List<int> { carId })).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public async Task<List<CarDetailsOutput>> GetCarsDetails(List<int> carIds)
    {
        var cars = await _car.Cars
            .Where(i => carIds.Contains(i.CarId))
            .ToListAsync();

        var output = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CarDetailsOutput>>(cars).ToList();
        return output;
    }
}
```

If you have a service that needs some car's data, you can inject `ICarData` and reuse it. But if you want to call `GetCarsDetails` in parallel with any function that also uses `CarContext` - it will fail. For example, you can't do this:

```
public async Task<ItemDetailsOutput> DoSomeLogic(List<int> carIds)
{
    var task1 = _carData.GetCarsDetails(carIds);
    var task2 = _shopData.GetSomeInformation();
    var task3 = _saleData.GetSomeInformation();
    var task4 = _offerData.GetSomeInformation();

    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3, task4);

    // Do some more stuff 
}
```

If any two of these tasks use `CarContext` this will not work.

I have one solution on my mind, but I'm not sure if it violates any SOLID principles. Here goes:

1. Create this extension:

   ```
    public static class DbContextExtensions
    {
        public static TDbContext CreateNew<TDbContext>(this TDbContext db) where TDbContext : DbContext
        {
            var connectionString = db.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString;
            var options = CreateBuilderOptions<TDbContext>(connectionString);
            return (TDbContext)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TDbContext), options);
        }

        private static DbContextOptions<TEntity> CreateBuilderOptions<TEntity>(string connectionString) where TEntity : DbContext
        {
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TEntity>();
            builder.UseSharedOptions(connectionString)
                .UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);

            return builder.Options;
        }
    }
   ```
2. Change methods that will be used in parallel process, like `_carData.GetCarsDetails`:

   ```
    public async Task<List<CarDetailsOutput>> GetCarsDetails(List<int> carIds)
    {
        await using var newCarContext = _car.CreateNew();

        var cars = await newCarContext.Cars
            .Where(i => carIds.Contains(i.CarId))
            .ToListAsync();

        var output = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CarDetailsOutput>>(cars).ToList();
        return output;
    }
   ```

With this, I don't have to think about where to inject factory and where to inject DbContext. I inject the needed DbContexts only. But then, when I know the method will be used in a parallel process, I create a new instance off of the DbContext that was originally injected.

I will not use transactions in parallel processes.

Will this work? Does this violate any SOLID principles?

Comment: Are you aware of `AddDbContextFactory`?

Comment: For parallel operations you will need to scope a DbContext per worker.  So DbContextFactory or Unit of Work scoping the DbContext.

Comment: @rshepp I am, but what If I don't need factory most of the time? Should I inject _carContext and carContextFactory?

Comment: @rhepp do you have any good examples with AddDbContextFactory?

Comment: With sql server there is a connection string parameter to allow multiple result sets.

Answer (score 1):

> using AddDbContext I can inject specific DbContext to any object for
> the lifespan of the request.

in this case,it shares the same dbcontext in same request,and as mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-6.0)

> The call to WhenAll(Task[]) method does not block the calling thread.

you were sharing the same dbcontext (not thread safe)in different threads

Creating new instance of Dbcontext with reflection/DbcontextFactory for each unit of work would both fix the error(it just differes in how to create a new instance within each unit of work,which solution is best -it's opinion based,you just need to make sure  not sharing the same instance of dbcontext with diffrent unit of work)

You could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor) related with Using a dbcontext factory and more details of [avoiding dbcontext threading issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#avoiding-dbcontext-threading-issues)  in the same doc